# OpenCL C++ cl_float4 operations

Tags: c++, overriding, opencl

I am using OpenCL cl_float4 type to represent geometrical vectors.

How can I create an override operators for cl_float4 ? Can I just put them in the separate file ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not.

This goes into the .h-File:

```
cl_float4
operator+ (const cl_float4& lhs, const cl_float4& rhs);
```

This goes into the .cpp file:

```
cl_float4
operator+ (const cl_float4& lhs, const cl_float4& rhs)
{
  cl_float4 result;
  for (uint i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
      result.s[i] = lhs.s[i] + rhs.s[i];
    }
  return result;
}
```

Or whatever other implementation you might like for the addition.